# STM32F4 Timer6 Register not setting

Tags: timer, stm32, bare-metal

Below is the code snippet of where I am setting my timer6 up

[Timer6 Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imtB1.png)

I used the datasheet register map
[Register map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIE32.png)

While debugging my prescaler value and auto reload arent being set.
Im not sure what is missing because when I debug my GPIO register I see them setting. Can someone share some insight or point me in the correct direction?

Thank you in advance
[debug periferals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITEEq.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code. You write `RCC->AHB1ENR` instead of `RCC->APB1ENR`, so the TIM6 clock is not enabled.

Comment: WOOOOOWWWW! Ive had tunnel vision for like 2 days now ! Thank you